# SQL SERVER CE Sub Query Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Below is the subquery I want to execute but VC# 2010 generates Exception when I Execute it.

Query:

```
("SELECT U.Name 
  FROM Users U,Installments I 
  WHERE U.ID=I.ID 
  AND I.Sr=(SELECT MAX(Sr) FROM Installments Group By ID ) 
  AND I.Date=(SELECT Date FROM Installments GROUP BY ID HAVING(Sr=Max(Sr)))"
 , Con))
```

Exception:

> There was an error parsing the query [ Token line number=1,Token line offset=69 Token in error =SELECT ]

Comment: Does date have to be wrapped in brackets? [Date]
Also, it seems like the "GROUP BY ID" is unnecessary in the first sub-select.

Comment: can you show your complete code?

Comment: you can't have SR in your having statement if it's not in your group by clause

Comment: i don't think so this query runs fine without the subquery but when i add subquery it throws exception can't figure out what's the problem in subquery as exception says at the start of subquery there is a problem

Comment: the database is designed in a way that users have unique id in them and this id is used for installments with serial no of installment hope you understand

Comment: @Mark H Kindly See my database design comment
@ EIVeejo the problem is in subquery so i think there is no need to show the whole bunch of code

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your query be `SELECT U.Name FROM Users AS U,Installments AS I WHERE U.ID=I.ID AND I.Sr=(SELECT MAX(Sr) FROM Installments Group By ID ) AND I.Date=(SELECT Date FROM Installments GROUP BY ID HAVING(Sr=Max(Sr)))`? You didn't specify the tables as U and I, just put the letters after the table names.

Comment: i don't think so this query runs fine without the subquery but when i add subquery it throws exception can't figure out what's the problem in subquery as exception says at the start of subquery there is a problem Any way with your answer it again tells same error at start of first select i-e first sub query